# Is it possible to determine astronomically/astrophysically whether other planets have ever encountered polarity reversal?

Tags: electromagnetism, astrophysics, planets, geophysics, magnetic-fields

We know of geomagnetic flip in Earth's history by studying geologic data. Given other planets in the system also possess a magnetic field leads to the assumption that such polarity reversal may not be unique to Earth.

Is it possible to determine geo-astrophysically whether such geomagnetic polarity reversal occurs on other planets?

Comment: Just to be clear, are you interested in the other planets in our Solar system, or exoplanets?

Comment: @ChrisWhite: No preference there. The mention of 'system' is based on the assumption that we may know more about our brother planets in the Solar System than exoplanets.

Answer (score 8):

### Regarding rocky planets in our solar system:

Sure, you just have to go check out enough of the rocks on the surface.

### Regarding exoplanets, and likely our own gas giants:

There are no methods by which we could determine such a thing with anything near today's technology.  ***Maybe*** someday in the distant future we might be able to measure the magnetic field of the planet directly (with [Zeeman Splitting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zeeman_effect) or something), and *might* notice if we happened to observe a reversal... but that's incredibly unlikely.

Theoretically that information *might somehow* be encoded in the circumplanetary environment... e.g. maybe there would be some signature encoded into a debris-disk / ring system; but the prospect of that both happening and being observable is pretty out there.